# ES6 run a function differently for multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a `sendEmail` function that needs to send different emails based on where the user is placed in the array. For example, I have the following data:

```
[ 
  { download: 'Release sale. 50% off!',
    user: 'test1@gmail.com' },
  { download: 'Release sale. 50% off!',
    user: 'test2@gmail.com' },
  { download: 'Release sale. 50% off!',
    user: 'test3@gmail.com' },
  { download: 'Release sale. 50% off!',
    user: 'test4@gmail.com' } 
]
[ 
  { download: 'Test',
    user: 'test5@gmail.com' 
  } 
]
```

For each array I need to accumulate all the `user` emails and the `download` string and run the following function:

```
await transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"Test" <noreply@test.com>',
    to: [email array here],
    subject: "Here is your file",
    text: `Here is your download: ${download}`
  })
```

Comment: A bit confused.  For any given array (I see 2 in your example: the one with test1-4 emails and an array with only test5 email ).  Across just 1 specific array, you would like to make an array of all of the emails (presumably to fill the section: [email array here]) and then for the 'text' node 'here is your download' - which 'download' node to you want to keep?  Or if there is a download node in the array, it will always be the same thing?

Comment: @Kyle For the array with download `Test`, I'd like to send a specific email to that 1 user with that download. For the other array, I'd like to send a mass email to all users with their download `Release sale. 50% off!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine your arrays into one array and iterate over it, calling your `sendMail()` method for each element.

```js
const users1 = [{
    download: 'Release sale. 50% off!',
    user: 'test1@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    download: 'Release sale. 50% off!',
    user: 'test2@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    download: 'Release sale. 50% off!',
    user: 'test3@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    download: 'Release sale. 50% off!',
    user: 'test4@gmail.com'
  }
];

const users2 = [{
  download: 'Test',
  user: 'test5@gmail.com'
}];

const allUsers = [...users1, ...users2];

const groupedUsers = allUsers.reduce((acc, u) => {
  const group = acc.find(x => x.download === u.download);

  if (group) {
    group.users.push(u.user);
    return acc;
  }

  return [...acc, {
    download: u.download,
    users: [u.user]
  }];
}, []);

console.log(groupedUsers)
```

With the `groupedUsers` list from above, you should be able to send emails to groups of users based on the `download` property.

```js
groupedUsers.forEach(async group => {
  await transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"Test" <noreply@test.com>',
    to: group.users,
    subject: "Here is your file",
    text: `Here is your download: ${group.download}`
  });
});
```

I used the spread (`...`) operator to combine the arrays, but you could also use `concat()` if you'd like. `const allUsers = users1.concat(users2);`

Comment: I can't merge the arrays, because the download is different for groups of users. For the array with download Test, I'd like to send a specific email to that 1 user with that download. For the other array, I'd like to send a mass email to all users with their download Release sale. 50% off!

Comment: Ah, looks like I missed the mark. I've added a grouping routine. Does that output look like what you need?

Answer (score 3):

This could be simply achieved by a reduce

```
const emailReduced = [ 
  { download: 'Release sale. 50% off!',
    user: 'test1@gmail.com' },
  { download: 'Release sale. 50% off!',
    user: 'test2@gmail.com' },
  { download: 'Release sale. 50% off!',
    user: 'test3@gmail.com' },
  { download: 'Release sale. 50% off!',
    user: 'test4@gmail.com' } 
].reduce((acc,{download, user}) => {
  return {
    ...acc,
    to: [...acc.to, user],
    text: `Here is your download: ${download}`
  }
}, {from: 'test <test@noreply.com>', subject: 'here is your file', to:[]})

await transporter.sendMail(emailReduced)
```

Comment: For the array with download Test, I'd like to send a specific email to that 1 user with that download. For the other array, I'd like to send a mass email to all users with their download Release sale. 50% off!

Comment: Also, there is no way to determine how many arrays there are. Right now there are "2" different downloads, but can be "3" or "4" in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
     var objArr = [ 
       { download: 'Release sale. 50% off!',
         user: 'test1@gmail.com' },
         { download: 'Release sale. 50% off!',
         user: 'test2@gmail.com' },
         { download: 'Release sale. 50% off!',
          user: 'test3@gmail.com' },
          { download: 'Release sale. 50% off!',
         user: 'test4@gmail.com' } 
       ]
      let obj = {}
          // Visit non-inherited enumerable keys
       ObjArr.map((data, idx) => {
          console.log(data.download);
          obj = {...obj, ...data.download}
        });
       Console.log(obj); //it wil have the consolidated list of user email yo needed for first array
```